# McNemar's test with multiple comparisons

Tags: classification, multiple-comparisons, mcnemar-test

I would like to test the difference between two classification outcomes for statistical significance using [McNemar's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test), but I am unsure how to best account for multiple comparisons.

The setting is as follows (see plot below):

I have obtained two classification accuracies based on the same dataset (solid line vs. dashed line) over multiple levels of an ordinal independent variable (x-axis). For each level of this ordinal variable (i.e. at each tick on the x-axis), I would like to run a McNemar's test to compare the classification outcomes. This means that I would have to run a total of 6 McNemar's tests.

[image]

To complicate things further, there is another more global nominal independent variable involved. Let's call it A. For each level of A, I have obtained a plot as shown above, and there are 7 levels. This means that, in total, I would have to run 7 x 6 = 42 McNemar's tests.

Now, I'm wondering at which level I have to account for multiple comparisons. I am convinced that at least at each level of A, I should correct for multiple comparisons with e.g. a Bonferroni correction (i.e. divide my alpha by 6). However, I'm unsure whether I need to also apply a correction **across** levels of A, i.e. perform each of the total 42 McNemar's tests with alpha/42.

Which of the two possible corrections is more appropriate? Or should I use a different approach altogether?